# Determine if an array[1...n] is a max heap

Tags: c

Was trying to search for an algorithm to determine if an array is a max-heap and came across this code. Would this code work for an array of arr[1...n]? And what is the (2*i+2) in arr[i] >= arr[2*i + 2] representing? From my understanding the left child of a max-heap should return 2*i instead of 2*i+2

```
/ Returns true if arr[i..n-1] represents a 
// max-heap 
bool isHeap(int arr[], int i, int n) 
{ 
// If a leaf node 
if (i > (n - 2)/2) 
    return true; 

// If an internal node and is greater than its children, and 
// same is recursively true for the children 
if (arr[i] >= arr[2*i + 1] && arr[i] >= arr[2*i + 2] && 
    isHeap(arr, 2*i + 1, n) && isHeap(arr, 2*i + 2, n)) 
    return true; 

return false; 
}
```

Comment: Heaps can either be zero-based, or one-based, which is to say that the root element can either be stored in array[0] or array[1]. Your understanding indicates that you expect a one-based heap. The code is a zero-based heap.

Comment: Oh i see, is there any way i can edit this code such that it is able to work on a one-based heap? I tried changing the 2i+2 to 2i but that alters the results of the code

Comment: You need 3 changes: 1) the array elements must be stored in indexes 1 through `n`, 2) the code must use index 1 as the index of the root element, 3) make the change you mentioned in your comment. If that isn't working, you'll need to post a [mcve], along with sample input, and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

For 0-based arrays, the children of `i` are `2i+1` and `2i+2` (children of 0 are 1 and 2; children of 1 are 3 and 4; etc.)

For 1-based arrays, the children are `2i` and `2i+1` (children of 1 are 2 and 3; children of 2 are 3 and 4; etc.)

Comment: Oh i see, is there any way i can edit this code such that it is able to work on a one-based heap? I tried changing the 2i+2 to 2i but that alters the results of the code

Comment: @ztw: 1-based arrays aren't natural in C. You can only do it by wasting the first element. So, you xan do thst but you'll need to change the whole program, not just this function. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Was given a question to determine if an array[1...n] is a max-heap so i had to design an algorithm based on a 1-based array instead of a 0-based if i understood the question correctly

Comment: @ztw: then your change should work provided you really call that function with a 1-based array and hive it values of i from 1 to n, inclusive.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Was calling the function on a 0-based array so i couldn't get the output that i wanted